# Subfloat with subcaption package: Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

I want to make a figure consisting of two subfigures.  Having read the Wikipedia subentry on [subfloats](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats), I tried to follow it exactly, so I did not use the `subfig` or `subfigure` package, only the `caption` and `subcaption` packages.  Nevertheless, I am getting a `Missing number, treated as zero` error, pointing to the line with `\begin{subfigure}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
% In preamble:
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


% In document:
\begin{figure}[htpb]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{width=0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A caption.}
\label{fig:my-figure}
\end{figure}
```

I am using TeXShop 2.47 on Mac OS X 10.8.1 (x86_64).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Note that the `includegraphics` command has syntax `width=<width>`, but the `subfigure` environment just has `\begin{subfigure}{width}`, not as `width=<width>`

I loaded the `graphicx` package with the `demo` option just for demonstration- remove it when you're working on your actual document :)

```
\documentclass{article}
% In preamble:
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
% In document:
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img_b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{A caption.}
    \label{fig:my-figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took me a long time to figure out that I was using the width argument and this was making my tex crash !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that the name of your file contains an underscore ("_"). We had the same problem and it was fixed changing the name of the file.